# Property closeOnBackdropClick doesnt work in a NbDialogService

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog, nebular

I am using Akveo/Nebular theme and I have a NBDialog element, I can see that exist the property closeOnBackdropClick in the documentation (For the dialog close/not when the user clicked outside the modal) and I want use.

Documentation por NBDialog
https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/dialog/overview#nbdialogservice

I tried put closeOnBackdropClick=false but doesnt work, The system cant find the property. Additional in the documentation I can see the property hasBackdrop but in my code works with the name backdrop

```
this.activeModal = this.modalService.open(CorporationGroupComponent, { size: 'lg', container: 'nb-layout', closeOnBackdropClick: false });
```

I want that the modal doesnt close when the user click out of the modal.

Comment: can you share some more code

Answer (score 0):

What Nebular version are you on? I just tried making a reproducible example and it works perfectly fine, please take a look:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-v1psfd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts

Both property names are taken from the documentation.